# Unable to Add Number to Sender Pool and Register for 10DLC for a number purchased through connected apps in twilio

Tags: twilio

I am encountering an issue with one of the numbers purchased through connected apps on Twilio. Although the number appears in my active numbers page, I am unable to locate it in order to add it to the sender pool of our messaging services. As a result, I am receiving error code 30034 indicating that the number is unregistered, preventing me from sending messages.